# C++ - Are there any differences between using `this` to initialize a member at the class level, versus `this` in the constructor?

Tags: c++, class, initialization

To my surprise, I learned that code like this actually works:

```
class A {
    B b;
    C c = this->b.GetC();
}
```

I guess I've been conditioned into thinking that `this` is essentially akin to `self` in Python. However, it also makes sense to me that at the class level we're declaring a template for which every instance of the class is to copy, and at the "declaration" level `this` shouldn't exist yet. But, C++ never fails to surprise, and the code above seems to work.

That said, is this bad style? What exactly are the differences between the code above, and simply initializing `C` in the constructor for `A`?

```
class A {
    B b;
    C c;

    A() {
        c = this->b.GetC();
    }
}
```

(or simply `A() : c(this->b.GetC()) {}`).

Comment: Are you aware of default member initializers?

Comment: Well, you could simply put `C c = b.getC()`. It will use `this` behind the scene.

Comment: I suppose, since I started with Python, that stuff at the class level is executed _outside_ the context of an object, and stuff in methods is executed _inside_ the context of an object (i.e., the latter assumes `this` exists, while the former does not). So `this` can exist at the class level in C++?

Comment: The fact that it surprised you shows that it might be a bad idea to use, as it might surprise or confuse others as well.

Comment: Self in python isn't a key word, nor is this. If you wanted to make your python look like C++ you could name it this instead.

Comment: @user3002473 Note that this is a default member initializers, so it's a default to use when compiling constructors. In that sense, it's still only being used in the context of a member.

Comment: @UKMonkey No `self` isn't a key word, correct, but you can't access the instance (whatever you call it, `self` or `this`) at the class level in Python regardless.

Comment: @UKMonkey [`this` is a keyword](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.key)

Comment: For those who doubt : https://godbolt.org/z/1FEsm9

Comment: @Brian Fair enough, I guess the question I'm more interested in then is if there are differences between the first and second definitions of `A`, since I never imagined you could use `this` outside a method.

Comment: @UKMonkey I did.  There is a link in my comment that takes you to the standards list of the keywords and `this` is listed among them.

Comment: @NathanOliver those look like c++ keywords. And given that it's missing def which is a key word in python, I think you're confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What exactly are the differences between the code above, and simply initializing `C` in the constructor for `A`?

This is completely equivalent to `A() : c(b.GetC()) {}`. There is no difference.

The only difference you will observe is when using multiple constructors. It will use the constructor's initializer instead of the default one if specified.

> the "declaration" level this shouldn't exist yet. But, C++ never fails to surprise, and the code above seems to work.
>
> So this can exist at the class level in C++?

No. The initializer is ran when the constructor is called. The member to initialize only exist when an instance is created.

Comment: Syntactic sugar to help the constructor medicine go down.

Answer (score 1):

> However, it also makes sense to me that at the class level we're declaring a template for which every instance of the class is to copy, and at the "declaration" level `this` shouldn't exist yet. But, C++ never fails to surprise, and the code above seems to work.

You are kind of right.  If you had

```
struct foo
{
    int bar;
    decltype(this->bar) baz;
};
```

then you would get a compiler error for using `this` at the top level of the class.

In your case though using `this` like

```
C c = this->b.GetC();
//or
C c{this->b.GetC()};
```

isn't actually using `this` at the top level.  A in class member initializer is just syntactic sugar for telling the class that if you do not manually initialize the member then you are to use the initializer provided.  So you aren't really using `this` in the body of the class, you're just using a shortcut.

> What exactly are the differences between the code above, and simply initializing `C` in the constructor for `A`?

The benefit is if you have some default value you want that memeber to have, you don't have to specify it in all of the constructors you create.  You do it once, and your covered.  If you ever need to change that value you can't mess it up because there is only one place to change it.  You can't forget to do it in a particular constructor which is really nice.

---

Do note that there is a case where you have to use `this` in a in class member initializer.  If the member you want to use comes from the dependent name, like a template base class, then you need to use `this` in order for the compiler to resolve the name.